# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00001920 (code=1), thread 8503

Tags: android, multithreading

I am using Samsung s3 mini for testing my app. I've been testing my app for months then suddenly it gave me the fatal signal. I don't know what happened but when I tried another device like my samsung tablet, my app worked without any problem. I tried just running the app without button functions just merely a layout. still gave me fatal signal. please help.

```
D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
W/ActivityThread: Application com.example.claude.afinal is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
I/System.out: Sending WAIT chunk
I/dalvikvm: Debugger is active
I/System.out: Debugger has connected
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: waiting for debugger to settle...
I/System.out: debugger has settled (1427)
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 79K, 12% free 9373K/10563K, paused 24ms, total 27ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 11.629MB for 1536016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 11% free 10872K/12103K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 31ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 11% free 10872K/12103K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 14.924MB for 3456016-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 9% free 14247K/15495K, paused 12ms+3ms, total 30ms
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
D/libEGL: loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
E/SensorManager: thread start
Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
D/SensorManager: registerListener :: handle = 0  name= MPU-6050 Accelerometer delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,),f+de(
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18935: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 18939: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.ViewGroup.onRtlPropertiesChanged, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar.onRtlPropertiesChanged
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 18830: Landroid/view/ViewGroup;.onRtlPropertiesChanged (I)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6f at 0x0007
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 468: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19456: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams.<init>, referenced from method android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout$LayoutParams.<init>
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve direct method 19456: Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;.<init> (Landroid/widget/LinearLayout$LayoutParams;)V
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0000
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 409: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 411: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2352K, 20% free 14457K/17927K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 450K, 13% free 15734K/17927K, paused 3ms+3ms, total 25ms
D/dalvikvm: WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 13ms
D/AbsListView: Get MotionRecognitionManager
E/Dynamiclayout: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: charAt: 0 >= length 0
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 300K, 12% free 16142K/18311K, paused 24ms, total 30ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Grow heap (frag case) to 35.916MB for 20070416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 6% free 35736K/37959K, paused 16ms+5ms, total 55ms
D/dalvikvm: GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 6% free 35737K/37959K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
I/dalvikvm-heap: Forcing collection of SoftReferences for 45158416-byte allocation
D/dalvikvm: GC_BEFORE_OOM freed 9K, 6% free 35727K/37959K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 45158416-byte allocation.
I/dalvikvm: "main" prio=5 tid=1 RUNNABLE
I/dalvikvm:   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41ab6508 self=0x41aa6788
I/dalvikvm:   | sysTid=8503 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[no-cpu-subsys] handle=1075453744
I/dalvikvm:   | schedstat=( 2253387454 450561516 1489 ) utm=193 stm=32 core=0
I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:447)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:781)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1963)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:672)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:114)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:206)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:182)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:192)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:451)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1138)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1053)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
I/dalvikvm:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4867)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
I/dalvikvm:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1007)
I/dalvikvm:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:774)
I/dalvikvm:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00001920 (code=1), thread 8503 (e.claude.afinal)
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

**UPDATE:**
This is the  `at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)`

codes

```
    * {@link android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES#KITKAT}, this is no longer the case.</p>
 */
public static Bitmap decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, Options opts) {
    // we don't throw in this case, thus allowing the caller to only check
    // the cache, and not force the image to be decoded.
    if (is == null) {
        return null;
    }

    Bitmap bm = null;

    Trace.traceBegin(Trace.TRACE_TAG_GRAPHICS, "decodeBitmap");
    try {
        if (is instanceof AssetManager.AssetInputStream) {
            final long asset = ((AssetManager.AssetInputStream) is).getNativeAsset();
            bm = nativeDecodeAsset(asset, outPadding, opts);
        } else {
            bm = decodeStreamInternal(is, outPadding, opts);
        }

        if (bm == null && opts != null && opts.inBitmap != null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Problem decoding into existing bitmap");
        }

        setDensityFromOptions(bm, opts);
    } finally {
        Trace.traceEnd(Trace.TRACE_TAG_GRAPHICS);
    }

    return bm;
}
```

My Samsung s3 mini is just Jelly Bean. I guess this is a problem?

Comment: What exactly do you do that causes the SIGSEGV?

Comment: you  log showing "Out of memory on a 45158416-byte allocation." please post code of what bitmap processing you are doing?

Comment: I have a button in the Activity_A. what it does is just to open Activity_B. when it opens Activity_B, that fatal signal appears and my terminates the app. I'm not doing anything in Activity_B. i disabled every function and anything that does actions. I tried Activity_B to be just like an EMPTY ACTIVITY. Uninstalled the app then run it again. still the same.

Comment: @gopal_patil I'm not doing any bitmap processing. I'm just getting string values from my database using json parsing.

Comment: What is your FAB icon? Are you sure you are not setting realy large image as an icon?

Comment: @user1779222is thank you sir. I have found another related topic which also suggested to adjust the resolution. I rechecked all of my icons and noticed that one icon has reached beyond the maximum resolution of my phone. I adjusted its resolution to 150x150 pixels, now it's now back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

you can try one of the two ways to resolve it.

1. options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
2. options.inSampleSize = 1;